# Timeout a web api after sometime if we don't get any response Angular TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, timeout, angular8

I am new to angular and I have having a trouble in web api. I am calling a web api and I want to do a task of calling one api in certain amount of time and if I don't get any response in that amount of time I need to execute another api. I am sharing my piece of code for better understanding. any help will be great. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zovZj.png)

Comment: What kind of solution do you expect or have in mind?

Comment: json will be great but any kind solutions will be fine.

Comment: `timeoutWith` in RxJs sounds as what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can set a rxjs timeout in the http request like so...

```
import { timeout, catchError, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
...
this.http.get(url, options)
    .pipe(
      timeout(5000),
      tap((data) => {
        // do stuff
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
```

The time is in ms, if the time is exceeded an error is thrown with a message that indicates it was because of the timeout.

You could also do this an interceptor, but you loose the ability to set different timeouts for different requests.